# Fail to connect to socket.io server on Window Server in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, socket.io, windows-server

I host a very simple node socket IO application on my Window Server, below are the code sample.

```
// socket.io 3.1.2"
const port = 30080;
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    credentials: false
}
});


io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log('On Connection');
  
    io.emit("message", 'Welcome to Socket Io.');
});
```

And I wrote some code to try connect to my socket IO server in a HTML File and work well. below are the code sample.

```
// <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
const socket = io("http://myserverip:30080", {
    withCredentials: false,
    extraHeaders: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('connect');
});

socket.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

But when I try to use those above code in my .NET Core web application, I get the error "**ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**". Even I publish my web application on the Window Server still getting the same error message.

I have tried http, https, ws and wss protocol. None of these work. How can I get this possibly working?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the following in your server side code:

```
httpServer.listen()
```

Do you have a reverse proxy between your client and the server?
I would expect no SSL related error based on you code.
I would also use socket.io version 4 just for future maintenance reasons.